# Get date of every monday of current week and the past 8 weeks?

Tags: php

I have a dropdown where i want to show the date of monday current week and past 8 weeks. How can i do it. Here is a sample of code on which i am working.

```
$maxDays=date('t');

for($i=0;$i<=$maxDays;$i++){
        echo  date("m-d-Y",strtotime("monday"));
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: you want to get current, and previous 2 months monday's date??

Comment: i want to get the date of every monday of current month and last 8 weeks

Comment: first you have to get all week numbers, from that you shud fetch mondays date.

Comment: can you please provide sample code in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> i want to get the date of every monday of current month and last 8 weeks

So, using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
    $date = new \DateTime;
    $weekDay = 'Monday';
    $ts = strtotime('first day of next month');
    $date->setTimestamp($ts);
    $month = $date->format('m');
    $thisMonthTs = strtotime('first day of this month');
    $date->setTimestamp($thisMonthTs);
    $thisMonth = $date->format('m');

    while ($month >= $thisMonth) {
        $ts = strtotime("previous $weekDay", $ts);
        $date->setTimestamp($ts);
        $month = $date->format('m');
        echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
        echo '<br>';
    }

    for ($n = 0; $n < 7; $n++) {
        $ts = strtotime("previous $weekDay", $ts);
        $date->setTimestamp($ts);
        echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

Solution may be improved, because it is a quick-trick. But all what you need it is datetime and strtotime

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [moment.php](https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php), a library in PHP to calculate all different kinds of dates/months/years. Your specific problem would come down to:

```
$m = new \Moment\Moment('2015-10-15T12:30:00', 'CET'); // last monday, that is
for($i=1;$i<=8;$i++){
    echo $m->subtractDays($i*7)->format("m-d-Y");  // $i multiplied by seven
    echo '<br>';
}
```